# OpenGL does not work in VMware?

Tags: android, opengl

I am new to Android, and am just starting to work through the examples in "Learn Android App Development".  When I try to "run as Android application", I get the following errors...

```
[2013-10-12 19:39:18 - Hello_World] ------------------------------
[2013-10-12 19:39:18 - Hello_World] Android Launch!
[2013-10-12 19:39:18 - Hello_World] adb is running normally.
[2013-10-12 19:39:18 - Hello_World] Performing chapter.two.hello_world.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-10-12 19:39:19 - Hello_World] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Android_4.2_Emulator_Nexus_7'
[2013-10-12 19:39:19 - Hello_World] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android_4.2_Emulator_Nexus_7'
[2013-10-12 19:39:27 - Emulator] extension WGL_ARB_make_current_read was not found
[2013-10-12 19:39:27 - Emulator] extension WGL_EXT_swap_control was not found
[2013-10-12 19:39:27 - Emulator] Failed to create pbuf surface for FB 0x3004
[2013-10-12 19:39:27 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2013-10-12 19:39:29 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio output failed
[2013-10-12 19:39:29 - Emulator] 
[2013-10-12 19:39:33 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2013-10-12 19:39:33 - Emulator] 
[2013-10-12 19:39:33 - Hello_World] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-10-12 19:39:33 - Hello_World] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-10-12 19:40:57 - Hello_World] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'chapter.two.hello_world.MainActivity activity launch'!
```

The two lines with "not found" at the end, and the very last line are actually in red ink.
Being brand new to Android development, I am not sure where the error is actually coming from.  Is it related to the fact that I am doing this on a Windows 7 x64 VMware VM, is it related to the host system (also a Windows 7 x64 system), is it related to the graphics card and its software, OpenGL, position of Mars in relationship to Venus, screen resolution, etc.???  My hardware is a HP pavilion AMD three Core processor.

Comment: Probably not, sounds like you have a GDI pixel format (OpenGL 1.1), which means you don't have what most people would consider a legitimate OpenGL driver. Certainly not adequate enough to simulate OpenGL ES

Comment: OK, old OpenGL software.  If this something that came with the host system, the video card, what?  What do I need to do to correct this?  Do I need to get new hardware or software (and from where)?

Comment: It is the reference software implementation that has shipped with Microsoft Windows since Win95 OSR2. You end up with this whenever there is no hardware driver installed; or when your Virtual Machine software/hardware does not have a hardware pass-through feature. If you have two GPUs and an appropriate chipset and VM software it is sometimes possible to dedicate one GPU to the VM. These days a lot of CPUs ship with somewhat decent integrated GPUs, so it is not outside the realm of possibility for this to work without an SLI/Cross-Fire configuration.